# ¿Cómo configuro supervisord para que no requiera sudo?

Tags: linux, bash

intento utilizar supervisord para ejecutar un checkeo de procesos. Pero todavía no pude siquiera levantarlo.

Cuando ejecuto: `supervisorctl reread` sin sudo sale:

```
error: <class 'PermissionError'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560
```

y con sudo:

```
No config updates to processes
```

Archivo del proceso:

```
[program=pruebasSupervisor]
command={path}/pruebaSupervisor.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile={path}/pruebasSupervisor.err.log
stdout_logfile={path}/pruebasSupervisor.out.log
```

El script en cuestión solamente tira en consola `date`

El archivo de configuración supervisord.conf está tal cual se instala por primera vez, no sé si hay que tocar algo.